# Google IMA iOS SDK `IMAAdsLoader -requestAdsWithRequest:` doesn't work on the 2nd time

Tags: ios, google-ima

I am using GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK (3.3.1) via Cocoapods to show video ads, Xcode 8.0. This is how I set up the adsLoader. Note I have `enableDebugMode = true`. This adsLoader is stored in `VKSharedAdManager.adsLoader` for reuse.

```
IMASettings *settings = [[IMASettings alloc] init];
settings.ppid = @"IMA_PPID_0";
settings.enableDebugMode = true;
settings.language = kLanguageCodeEnglish;
self.adsLoader = [[IMAAdsLoader alloc] initWithSettings:settings];
```

Then I make the request with that loader.

```
IMAAdDisplayContainer *displayContainer = [[IMAAdDisplayContainer alloc] initWithAdContainer:self.adRequest.adContainer companionSlots:nil];
    self.request = [[IMAAdsRequest alloc] initWithAdTagUrl:adTagUrl adDisplayContainer:displayContainer contentPlayhead:VKSharedAdManager.contentPlayhead userContext:nil];
    VKSharedAdManager.adsLoader.delegate = self;
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: requesting %@", self, adTagUrl);
    [VKSharedAdManager.adsLoader requestAdsWithRequest:self.request];
```

The first ads works fine, `IMAAdsLoaderDelegate` methods are called fine. The IMA loader debug log is as follows. (There are more but this is the beginning...)

```
2016-12-13 15:35:14.769 MyApp[5835:1419742] Core: (INFO) ima.loader.AdsLoaderWrapper: Requesting ads using new ads loader.
2016-12-13 15:35:14.963 MyApp[5835:1419742] Core: (INFO) ima.loader.AdsLoaderWrapper: requestAds, processing external request.
2016-12-13 15:35:14.964 MyApp[5835:1419742] Core: (INFO) ima.loader.SequentialAdsLoader: Enqueued new request.
2016-12-13 15:35:14.965 MyApp[5835:1419742] Core: (INFO) ima.loader.SequentialAdsLoader: Starting request from queue.
2016-12-13 15:35:15.257 MyApp[5835:1419742] Core: (INFO) ima.loader.AdSourceFetcher: Creating PlaylistSource.
2016-12-13 15:35:15.271 MyApp[5835:1419742] Core: (INFO) ima.loader.AdsLoaderWrapper: dispatchPlaylist_
...
...
```

Next, I close that video and then play another video. 
**PROBLEM:** Now the log just show this and nothing happens.

```
2016-12-13 15:37:59.266 MyApp[5835:1419742] Core: (INFO) ima.loader.AdsLoaderWrapper: Requesting ads using new ads loader.
```

Then for all next videos after there's no log at all. If I restart the app, then same thing happen. Only the first ad works. I have tried like 10+ times and there's one lucky time that it will work for all videos. All testing is done on iPad mini device with iOS 9.3.5. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is only one instance of `IMAAdsLoader` throughout the app. Have a look at the official doc:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/quickstart

> You should maintain only one instance of IMAAdsLoader for the entire
>   lifecycle of your app. To make additional ad requests, create a new
>   IMAAdsRequest object but re-use the same IMAAdsLoader. For more info
>   see our FAQ.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I only create one `IMAAdsLoader` object.